# JPA CriteriaBuilder - filter where integer_field = count of inner query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

JPA CriteriaBuilder is quite difficult for me to get my head around when it comes to building complex queries like the following, how do i go about this?

```
SELECT * FROM offers o1
WHERE o1.offer_id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT offer_id 
    FROM offers o2
    WHERE o2.max_links_per_cardholder = 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM linked_offers lo
        WHERE lo.card_id IN 
        (
            SELECT pc.card_id 
            FROM payment_cards pc 
            WHERE pc.cardholder_id = 'BWCI4TRMBRAWAAFL6LGHXR8WAYV6HA'
        )
    )
);
```

**Does anyone have any tips on how to derive the Predicate for this using JPA CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder and Root<>?**